# Suggested edits not syntax highlighting based on tags

Tags: feature-request, bug, suggested-edits, syntax-highlighting

I just came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3255512).

Markdown:

[image]

Rendered:

[image]

The editor removed the manual syntax highlighting - `<!-- language: c++ -->` (which doesn't change anything, since the C++ tag is there).

Even though the C++ tag causing syntax highlighting in [the actual post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700880/converting-4byte-hex-string-to-integer), there is no syntax highlighting visible on the right-side above.

So, since tags don't seem to cause syntax highlighting in suggested edits, it now looks like the editor removed the syntax highlighting altogether (but the edit is definitely 'too minor').

Admittedly this is a bit of a corner case, but syntax highlighting would make reviewing a more colourful experience in anyway.

Can we change the UI to display tag-based syntax highlighting in suggested edits?
Or is there a good reason we don't?

Not sure if this is a feature request or a bug.

**Side note:**

The lack of tag-based syntax highlighting is not consistent with [the revision history UI](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19700880/revisions):

[image]