# How to stop this 'Code Appearance Edited' machine?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

[Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823468/alexandre?tab=activity) and resulting [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823468/alexandre?tab=reputation)

Anything a normal user can do to stop that?

Narrowing down the edits (some people simply clicked one or two and said *oh, nothing wrong with that*)

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3294659),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295676),
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295488),
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295413),
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295375),
[6](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295336),
[7](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295271),
[8](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295238),
[9](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295215),
[10](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295211),
[11](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295129),
[12](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295097),
[13](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3295048),
[14](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3294981),
[15](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3294972),
[16](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3294837)

so 16 out of 20 is a good ratio? Is this what you're saying?

## update

I have originally deleted this question, but after just  a few days the [problem came back](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823468/alexandre?tab=reputation).

Anything we're going to do about that?

Comment: It looks like proper edits , so what is the problem ?

Comment: Many of the edits are good. There are a _few_ there where the suggested edit has introduced code formatting where they shouldn't - those should have been rejected but have not been :(

Comment: With those specific cases, a comment to the editor with a rollback would be my choice.

Comment: @Habib massive indentation is a proper edit while theyre other things that could be fixed

Comment: @mehow Which one are you referring to that was so bad?

Comment: Oh, you mean those should have been rejected as too minor?

Comment: Just looking at the accepted, there seems to have more edits that should have been rejected that weren't. I feel the reviewers of those need a break as much as the person doing those edits need a warning of some kind.

Comment: Nothing we can do. Nothing here is catastrophic.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau exactly my point! 16 out of 20 are too minor. That's alarming in both directions - the person who suggests the edits and the reviewers who accept it!

Comment: I need to ask this as a learning moment. I review suggested edits, and sure, some of these are minor... but most I would not consider *too minor*. With `1`, they corrected a spelling mistake as well as added improved indentation. They put age and person in code blocks, which I don't necessarily agree with, but I don't see anything wrong with it. `2` I agree is a little too minor. Again, `3` looks good to me. Is `4` too minor? His changes improved readability IMO. I could go on, but maybe these are enough to help me learn the *right* way. `7` was approved by the OP. Surely, that means its ok?

Comment: @Gray see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203689/serial-pointless-editing)

Comment: Four of the posts you linked to were already rejected, which is one of the two options we have for stopping such edits. (The other being improve upon it.)  Several of the others are borderline, but nothing I'd reject outright. I probably would have improved/approved all of these and rejected none.

Comment: The problem came back — **what problem**? Apparently you object to this user's edits, but I looked at a couple of the ones you linked directly and they seem fine to me. What do you think is wrong with those edits?